# Why can't receive rtp stream on Ubuntu?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, vlc, streaming

I am streaming the desktop over rtp using ffmpeg from computer A. Here is my ffmpeg code:

```
ffmpeg -f x11grab -framerate 25 -video_size 1920x1080 -i :1.0 -c:v libx264 -preset fast -pix_fmt bgr0 -b:v 3M -g 25 -an -f rtp_mpegts rtp://230.0.0.1:5005
```

I can play the live stream in vlc in the computer A in "rtp://@230.0.0.1:5005". But I can't play the stream from computer B that is in the same network with computer A by trying to open "rtp://@230.0.0.1:5005" in VLC.

If I stream an mp4 file over http, than computer B is able to play it. For http streaming, I simply go to the VLC -> Media -> Stream -> (Adding the mp4 file), and stream in HTTP format in 8080 port on A. Then open it in VLC on the machine B with "http://serverIP:portnumber".

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: have you ruled out firewall rules?

Comment: Yes, it is inactive. When I run the "sudo ufw status" command, says "inactive". Are there any other firewall rules that I should check?

Comment: on both machines?

Comment: Yes. I am really confused about why it is not working. In the other hand, if firewall blocks something, then computer B should not receive the http stream too I think.

Comment: that's different: in the HTTP case, B is initiating the connecting, in the RTP case, A simply sends an UDP stream to the target address.

Comment: Thanks, I got it now. Any other advice or help about problem?

Comment: you could use wireshark to figure out whether the packets arrive at B

Comment: You haven't added the working vlc streaming command. Just like the on currently in the answer, how do you stream, when it works? `ffmpeg ...`

Comment: I am not using any streaming command when it works. I simply do the  instructions in this answer to stream: https://askubuntu.com/a/574124/1346719

Comment: What if you stream _from_ computer B to computers A and B? Try to isolate any differences and problems going in each direction, from each computer, to see potenial problem areas.

Comment: I tried each direction... No difference unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why can't receive rtp stream on Ubuntu?

Because you are using a multicast address `230.0.0.1` and your current setup does not have a multicast path between the two hosts.

So, one way to solve the problem right now is to use unicast transmission. Just change the `230.0.0.1` with the ip address of the host you are going to be watching from.

```
ffmpeg -f x11grab -framerate 25 -video_size 1920x1080 -i :1.0 -c:v libx264 -preset fast -pix_fmt bgr0 -b:v 3M -g 25 -an -f rtp_mpegts rtp://a.b.c.d:5005
```

where `a.b.c.d` is the IP address of the Ubuntu host.

Then, on the Ubuntu host you can do:

```
vlc rtp://@:5005
```

Comment: Thanks, I have used unicast transmission and it worked, computer B is able to see the stream. But, you said "In order for that to work you need all hosts to be able to handle multicast", how do I make all machines to be able to handle multicast? When I run "ifconfig" command on both computers, I see "MULTICAST" keyword, therefore I understand that MULTICAST is enabled on both computers.

Comment: You might want to read something like [How to enable multicast on linux network interface](https://myopsblog.wordpress.com/2016/07/11/how-to-enable-multicast-on-linux-network-interface/) and ask a new question about it if you get stuck with something. Although related, it is outside the scope of this question.

Comment: Thanks! I made the configurations described in the link, now multicast streaming is working properly. Maybe I missed something before this.